# How to use onmouseover to open link in another frame?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, onmouseover, frameset

For a frameset, i want to open a link from page of A frame by using onmouseover and open it in another B frame? when mouseover the link from A frame, it will open the page on B frame. Give a hint.

Comment: Do you talk about '<frame></frame>' or '<iframe></iframe>'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I worked with `<frame>` it has taking a long time ago (seven or more years).

Because you didn't post any html sourcode :-|, I created a theoretical situation:

```
<html>
    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript">
       function nullRand () {
         //document.getElementById("frameBid").src = "myNewInternalPage.html";
           document.getElementById("frameBid").src = document.getElementById("frameAid").src;
        }
      </script>
    </head>
    <frameset cols="25,*" frameborder="no" border="0" framespacing="0" framepadding="0">
       <frame id="frameAid" name="frameAname" src="myHtmlFile.html" noresize>
       <frame id="frameBid" name="frameBname" src="" noresize>
    </frameset>
</html>
```

SIn my theoretical file 'myNewInternalPage.html' you have to instert the method call

```
<a href="#" onMouseOver="parent.nullRand()">An link</a>
```

Note: `frame` is not approiate to show external content. That's why `iframe` exists.

***Update:***

After a hard fight with the OP I got something to my hands. Here is a solution:

1st: Replace the old Javascript code from 'nullRand()' with the new one

```
function nullRand (linkObject)
{
  document.getElementById("frameBid").src = linkObject.href; // The new way to access to a frame
  //top.frames["center"]..src = linkObject.href; <-- The old way to access to a frame */
}
```

2nd: Modyfiy the a tag -where the radio streams are listed- as follow:

```
<a href="the Url from your radiostream" ... onMouseOver="parent.nullRand(this)">...</a>
```

So it should work. In my eyes you should think about a new concept for your task.

Comment: not work.. when mouseover the link in frame A, it open default page of frame B, not open the content of Frame A into Frame B.

Comment: I have to apologize for my fault. I did overseen that you asked for the transfer the content in FrameA into FrameB. So I updated the code of my answer. Do you want to transfer the content page there link points or just the page that contains the link?

Comment: ok i tell background of the case. the default content of frame B is show: Click Radio Name. The content of frame A has a list of radio name. i want a mouse over the radio name then it will open the radio player on frame B. but after i use your code, it's not open radio player but open the default content of frame B that show the: Click Radio Name. my frameset is http://radiotoolbarinframe.notlong.com/ . i want the frameset modified with onmouseover function when mouse over the radio names.

Comment: So you want show the content page - which the links does point- in FrameB. As I wrote the tag <frame> does not support showing content from external pages. What you have to do is to include an <iframe> in the content page of FrameB. I'll try that out.

Comment: include an <iframe> in the content page of FrameB? please show me the code.

Comment: how to change the frame into iframe? because im using frameset.

Comment: actually, after make deppest thinking, i think onmouseover function for opening radio player is not smart option because the player will change accidently if user mouse over the radio name link. i place the player on top of the page, and it will change the radio station when user move cursor through it to type on address bar or to do anything. so it's not necessary for me for this case. anyway thanks.

Comment: 1st: You can use onClick instead of onMouseOver
2nd: Open your page - for FrameB- into an editor and add <iframe id="myiframe" src=""></iframe> within the <body> section
3rd: You need a modified javascript code to read the value from src attribute of clicked link and modifiy the src attribute from iframe to with it.

Comment: my problem is to use onmouseover function, no need the iframe attribute.

Comment: As I wrote why don't you use the onClick event?

Comment: because i want onmousover function..onclick event is slow and annoying when onmouseover event is faster way to use..

Comment: why u advise me to use iframe? i think it not necessary if using frame still same with iframe function in this case

Comment: At this point I have to say, unless you don't provide any example source we are unable to help you. so it is up to you what you to decide.

Comment: to see the source code, view source code of the webpage: http://radiotoolbarinframe.notlong.com . i want, when mouse over the radio name, it will open radio player at another frame.

Comment: it work..first i tried it offline...nothing happen.. then i upload the test code..it nice as i want! thanks..topic closed..